# How do I mock boto3's StreamingBody object for processing with BytesIO in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mocking, boto3

I'm unittesting a function that transforms an element from an S3 object into a pandas DataFrame and need to mock the returned StreamingBody object from boto3

**file.py**

```py
def object_to_df(self, key_name, dtypes):
    s3_object = self.get_object(key_name=key_name)
    if s3_object is not None:
        object_df = pandas.read_csv(
            io.BytesIO(s3_object["Body"].read()), dtype=dtypes
        )
        return object_df
```

The response of self.get_object(key_name) is documented [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object)

```
{
    'Body': StreamingBody(),
    'DeleteMarker': True|False,
    'AcceptRanges': 'string',
    ...
}
```

So I need to mock that StreamingBody() object and have my mock function return that.

**test.py**

```py
import unittest
import pandas
from io import StringIO
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from path.to.file import custom_class
from botocore.response import StreamingBody

class TestS3Class(unittest.TestCase):
    """TestCase for path_to/file.py"""

    def setUp(self):
        """Creates an instance of the live class for testing"""
        self.s3_test_client = S3()


    @patch('path.to.class.get_object')
    def test_object_to_df(self, mock_get_object):
        """"""
        mock_response = {'Body': [{'Candidate': 'Black Panther', 'Votes': 3},
                        {'Candidate': 'Captain America: Civil War', 'Votes': 8},
                        {'Candidate': 'Guardians of the Galaxy', 'Votes': 8},
                        {'Candidate': "Thor: Ragnarok", 'Votes': 1}
                    ]}
        mock_stream = StreamingBody(StringIO(str(mock_response)), len(str(mock_response)))
        mock_get_object.return_value = mock_stream
        self.assertIsInstance(self.s3_test_client.object_to_df(key_name='key_name', dtypes=str), pandas.DataFrame)
```

But I'm running into `TypeError: 'StreamingBody' object is not subscriptable`

Any hints?

Comment: Did you get the solution? I'm exactly facing the same problem

Comment: @Tula, No I didn't figure it out. I took another approach - figuring those aws/pandas functions are themselves maintained and tested and there's not a lot of value to be had by implementing that granular of a unit test.

Answer (score 8):

The S3 client returns a dict and your mocked S3 client is returning a StreamingBody. Your mocked S3 client should return something like

```py
body_json = {
    'Body': [
        {'Candidate': 'Black Panther', 'Votes': 3},
        {'Candidate': 'Captain America: Civil War', 'Votes': 8},
        {'Candidate': 'Guardians of the Galaxy', 'Votes': 8},
        {'Candidate': "Thor: Ragnarok", 'Votes': 1},
    ]
}

body_encoded = json.dumps(body_json).encode('utf-8')

body = StreamingBody(
    StringIO(body_encoded),
    len(body_encoded)
)

mocked_response = {
    'Body': body,
    ...
}

mock_get_object.return_value = mocked_response
```

Comment: `json.dump` won't work, I think you mean `json.dumps`. this solution did not work for me, Akshay kamath B did

Answer (score 5):

The below code worked for me. referred answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64642433/12385686

```
import json
from botocore.response import StreamingBody
import io
    
body_json = {
    'Body': [
        {'Candidate': 'Black Panther', 'Votes': 3},
        {'Candidate': 'Captain America: Civil War', 'Votes': 8},
        {'Candidate': 'Guardians of the Galaxy', 'Votes': 8},
        {'Candidate': "Thor: Ragnarok", 'Votes': 1}
    ]
}

body_encoded = json.dumps(body_json).encode()

body = StreamingBody(
    io.BytesIO(body_encoded),
    len(body_encoded)
)

mocked_response = {
    'Body': body,
    ...
}

mock_get_object.return_value = mocked_response
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to mock a `.json` file as response

```
# my_file.json
{
    "key1": "value_1",
    "key2": "value_2",
    "key3": "value_3"
}
```

Using `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO` in @YisusThreepwood answer works

```
body = StreamingBody(
    BytesIO(body_encoded),
    len(body_encoded)
)
```

Otherwise you get

> TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes.

Answer (score 0):

works for me I used like

```
@patch('src.handler.boto3.client')
def test_AccountIDs(self, client:MagicMock):
    client.return_value = s3_client
    
    body_encoded = open('accounts.csv').read().encode()
    mock_stream = StreamingBody(io.BytesIO(body_encoded),len(body_encoded))
    s3_stubber.add_response('get_object', { 'Body' : mock_stream})

    with s3_stubber:
        res = handler.getAccountIDs()
        self.assertListEqual(res,['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

thanks for the solution !!!! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).